# PhoneGap Cordova 3.3 - Splash Screens

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I've read so much on these stupid splash screens I have no idea why it wont work...

I'm going to run through everything because there are so many examples on the net which are different but work for some and not others... dont know why and also if someone from Adobe PhoneGap is reading, your documentation is shocking.

right, I'm using PhoneGap build which currently only supports cordova 3.3, so I installed that specific version:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.3
```

then created a project

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

then since I have an android, add android support

```
cordova platform add android
```

I then added the SplashScreen plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

Then updated the config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Then built the android package

```
cordova build android
```

then added the following images:

```
hello/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png
hello/platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/splash.png
hello/platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/splash.png
hello/platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/splash.png
```

then zipped up the `hello` folder

boshed it up to https://build.phonegap.com, installed on my phone and no splash screen...

any help please!!!

Comment: please note I did this exactly as stated above

Comment: It doesn't show any splash screen and it isn't even blank for 5 seconds, goes straight to the app.

Comment: I don't see your reference to the splash images in your config file. Where is your <gap:splash src="splash.png" /> tag?